# Slow evaluation of Recurrence plot data from NDSolve: Performance Tuning

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, performance-tuning, nonlinear

I am trying to use a [recurrence plot](http://www.recurrence-plot.tk/glance.php) to pinpoint the location when a system re-visits a previous point in its phase portrait.  The system (a [thin liquid film](http://www.mis.mpg.de/applan/research/viscousthinfilms.html)) is governed by a non-linear differential equation and is quite easily solved using `NDSolve` as shown:

```
{xMin, xMax} = {-(π/0.0677), π/0.0677}; 
k = 0.0677; 
TMax = 1650; 
m = 5; 
S = 100; 
Ga = -3^(-1); 
Quiet[uSolpbc = 
     u /. NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], 
        t] == (-S)*D[u[t, x]^3*D[u[t, x], x, x, x], x] + 
                 Ga*D[u[t, x]^3*D[u[t, x], x], x] - 
        m*D[(u[t, x]/(1 + u[t, x]))^2*
                       D[u[t, x], x], x], 
      u[0, x] == 1 - 0.01*Cos[k*x], u[t, xMin] == u[t, xMax],                  
      Derivative[0, 1]*u[t, xMin] == Derivative[0, 1]*u[t, xMax],                  
      Derivative[0, 2]*u[t, xMin] == Derivative[0, 2]*u[t, xMax],                  
      Derivative[0, 3]*u[t, xMin] == Derivative[0, 3]*u[t, xMax]}, 
     u, {t, 0, TMax}, {x, xMin, xMax}, MaxSteps -> 100000, 
     Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "Method" -> "LSODA", "TemporalVariable" -> t,"SpatialDiscretization" ->                      {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 800, "MaxPoints" -> 1200, 
                  "DifferenceOrder" -> 5}}][[1]]]
```

The film profile is plotted as:

`Plot[uSolpbc[0.99 TMax, x], {x, xMin, xMax}`]

[image: film profile]

I am coding the Recurrence Plot in a block:

```
Block[{stepSize = 2, end = TMax, tt, ττ, rd},
 rd = ParallelTable[
   UnitStep[
    0.01 - Norm[uSolpbc[tt, 0] - uSolpbc[ττ, 0], 2]], {tt, 
    0, end, stepSize}, {ττ, 0, end, stepSize}];
 MatrixPlot[rd]]
```

[image: recurrence plot, rough version]

The grainy nature of the plot can be improved by choosing a smaller time step; say, `stepSize = 1/20` or less.  However, the current `stepSize` of 2 itself is quite slow (`Timing` reveals 0.344 seconds; `AbsoluteTiming` reveals 3.33 seconds).

I have a feeling that it is the nested nature of these functions (`ParallelTable`, `UnitStep` and `Norm`) that is taking a long time. Is there some way I can improve this?  Currently, choosing a much smaller time step leads to an "out of memory" error (I have ~ 8 GB of memory that is exhausted!).

It is not `Nest` or `Map` that I am looking for, and if it is, I guess I am lost on its application in this case.

Comment: You can use `Table` or get the definition of the interpolating function to the subkernels, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can use the new function `DistanceMatrix[]` for the purpose; this avoids repeated computations (since the underlying matrix is symmetric).

```
With[{stepSize = 2, end = TMax},
     MatrixPlot[UnitStep[0.01 - DistanceMatrix[uSolpbc[Range[0, end, stepSize], 0]]]]]
```

and your plot is produced very quickly, without the need to invoke parallelization.

Comment: Elegant in its simplicity and requires about `2/7` the time of my solution. (+1).

Comment: ...and if you hadn't tried it out yet, @drN, you could go as fine as `stepSize = 1/2` with little effort!

Comment: Just did. Thank you - it works great! Could you however also add that this needs ``Needs["HierarchicalClustering`"]`` in your answer?  Without that, I get an error message.  Really nice solution.

Comment: It's supposed to be built-in in version 10... from your comment, I presume you're on an older version?

Comment: I have 10.2?  I suppose the latest version is >10.2 then.  Need to check with my university if they can update.

Comment: Ah. It became built-in in 10.3, @drN. The current version is 10.4.1 tho.

Answer (score 3):

The plot in the question must have been obtained with `stepSize = 15`, not `stepSize = 2`.  Using the latter value gives a smooth plot,

[image]

The computation takes about 78 sec on my PC.  To address the specific issue in the question, the run time can be reduced by two orders of magnitude using

```
Block[{stepSize = 2, end = TMax, tt, rd}, 
    tSolpbc = Table[uSolpbc[tt, 0], {tt, 0, end, stepSize}]; 
    rd = ParallelTable[
        UnitStep[0.01 - Norm[tSolpbc[[nt]] - tSolpbc[[nτ]], 2]], 
        {nt, end/stepSize}, {nτ, end/stepSize}]; MatrixPlot[rd]]
```

which produces the same plot.  Evidently, most of the run time used in the original computation was consumed by computing `uSolpbc` `(end/stepSize)^2` times.  The revised computation computes it only `end/stepSize` times.

Comment: You are correct, my mistake... the stepSize was indeed 15. I was thinking "2" in my head.  Thank you for the solution.